# How to track monthly contributions to Atlassian Confluence?

Tags: confluence

We are trying to encourage our team to document more (yes, it's like getting children to eat their vegetables).

Our plan is to have a monthly leaderboard of users in our space, by Edits and Comments (we don't want to count labels or likes).  After about a day of messing around with widgets and such, we have come up with the Contributors Summary, but there is no date range for that.  It's for all time.  We need the exact same data, but for the past month.

Is there a macro/widget/etc that gives similar stats as the Contributors Summary, but can be restricted to a date range, i.e. -30d to present?  Or perhaps a hidden parameter we can provide in the URL?